# SQL to duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the easiest way to duplicate all records in a table `m` times? The catch is that the duplication has to keep the old order. I.e., If all I had were records

```
A, B, & C,
```

after duplication of 3 times, I should get

```
A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, & C,
```

instead of anything else, like A,A,A,B,…, etc.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If A, B, and C are records in a table, then they are inherently unordered.  Do you have a column that specifies ordering?

Comment: @Gordon is right. Still if you want to do messy things try a cursor, they are good at doing the wrong thing.

Comment: "Do you have a column that specifies ordering?" That's for sure, and you need to add surrogate keys after the duplication for sure as well .

Comment: I think you may be misusing the term replication as it relates to SQL Server.

Comment: @jean, I can easily replicate all records in my table `m` times using just SQL, not cursor, but it is the ordering that stops me.

Comment: @Zane, Oh, didn't know. should I change it to, say duplicate?

Comment: well, you asked that to be done in a specific order and a cursor ill do RBAR in a specific order.

Comment: @xpt yeah that works. Here's a link for some more info on [replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to return rows in the original order, you can do that as:

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
order by n.n, t.ordercol;
```

The `order by` guarantees the ordering.  It is dependent on the original column being ordered.

By the way, this is the same if you use `union all`, or a recursive CTE to generate the data (these are reasonable alternatives).  The ordering is *not* guaranteed in the result set unless you use `order by`.

Comment: Hi gordon , does `Insert into targetTable select col From sourceTable Order by col` gaurantee ordering of records inserted

Comment: SQL Server sort of guarantees this.  It guarantees that an identity column will be assigned in the sort order.  Tables are inherently unordered, so the actual insertion order shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I need to have a ROW_NUMBER() surrogate keys for all the duplicated record. Is that possible? Oh, got it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will give you an idea:-

```
DECLARE @Start int = 1
DECLARE @Stop int = 5
DECLARE @tbl table
(
   oldValue varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl
    SELECT name FROM TABLE_01

WHILE @start<=@stop
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_01
    SELECT oldValue FROM @tableVariable

    SET @start = @start + 1 
  END
```

SINCE you said duplicate all records..so first insert all records in table variable. then using while loop to insert all records in same table n number of times.